# GWT & GDATA: given a single use token, trying to retrieve a list of documents

Tags: java, gwt, gdata, google-docs, authsub

I'm following this guide:
http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html

I just need to retrieve a token and use it to get a list of documents, so i used AuthSub to get a single use token, and this seems to work: i get a string like this

```
1/BM14a4NnfKf........
```

Now i'm trying to do this: http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#Versioning

1) Specifying a version

2) Retrieving a list of documents

I'm managing these functions in a class called TokenServiceImpl:

```
package mui.server.services;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import mui.client.services.TokenService;

import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService;
import com.google.gdata.client.http.AuthSubUtil;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.DocumentListEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.DocumentListFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

public class TokenServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        TokenService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String nextUrl = "";
    String scope = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/";
    boolean secure = false; // set secure=true to request secure AuthSub tokens
    boolean session = true;
    String authSubUrl = "";

    @Override
    public String getToken(String requestUri) {
        nextUrl = requestUri;
        authSubUrl = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(nextUrl, scope, secure, session);

        return ", clicca <a href='" + authSubUrl
                + "'>qui</a> per regalarmi un token! (esempio Google Docs)";

    }

    @Override
    public String getDocsInfo(String token) {
        String elenco=", grazie del token, eccolo qui:<br> " + token + "<br>";

        DocsService client = new DocsService("yourCo-yourAppName-v1");
        client.setProtocolVersion(DocsService.Versions.V2);


        try {
            URL feedUri = new URL(
                    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/");
            DocumentListFeed feed = client.getFeed(feedUri, DocumentListFeed.class);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return elenco;
    }


}
```

But in the method getDocsInfo (which get the string "token", the token previously retrieved) the only row

```
DocumentListFeed feed = client.getFeed(feedUri, DocumentListFeed.class);
```

gives me errors:

```
22-gen-2012 11.14.19 com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector handleResponse
AVVERTENZA: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {googlelogin=WWW-Authenticate: GoogleLogin realm="http://www.google.com/accounts"}
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: OK
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Authorization required</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Authorization required</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:600)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:631)
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
    at mui.server.services.TokenServiceImpl.getDocsInfo(TokenServiceImpl.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

What am I missing? I'm really confused... I'm at the beginning with all this, maybe it's something stupid... but is't it just what's exactly written in the guide?
And here in this example
http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#ListDocs
where do I need to use the token i retrieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two steps more were required:

1) change the token to "sessionToken":

```
    String sessionToken = AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken(token, null);
```

2) associate the token to the client:

```
    DocsService client = new DocsService("yourCo-yourAppName-v1");
    client.setAuthSubToken(sessionToken);
```